# What are the kernels of ring homomorphisms that contain the polynomial $X^2+1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\mathbb{R}[X]$ be the ring of polynomials over the field of real numbers.
>
> Write down two ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{R}[X]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ whose kernels contain the polynomial $X^2+1$.

My attempt/thoughts:

I think that what the exercise requires us to do is to define two functions, say $\theta,\phi:\mathbb{R}[X]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, and then show that these functions are ring homomorphisms. Then we have to show that the kernel of each function contains the polynomial $X^2+1$, i.e. show that $X^2+1\in\ker\theta$ and $X^2+1\in\ker\phi$.

But I am struggling to think of such functions; I don't know how to derive them.

I would appreciate any hints/help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, we know that in $\Bbb{C}$, there are two zeroes of $x^2+1$: $i$ and $-i$. Therefore, we can simply make $\theta$ the evaluation $f \rightarrow f(i)$ and $\phi$ the evaluation homomorphism $f \rightarrow f(-i)$. In both of these cases, when $f=x^2+1$, the homomophisms evaluate to $0$:

$$\theta(x^2+1)=i^2+1=-1+1=0$$
$$\phi(x^2+1)=(-i)^2+1=-1+1=0$$

Therefore, these evaluation homomorphisms are two ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb{R}[X]$ to $\Bbb{C}$ such that $x^2+1$ are in the kernel.